# Group or Join multiple data events without a common event id

Tags: azure-log-analytics, azure-data-explorer

Source data:

| Host | Alert | EventTime | EventStatus |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| host1 | WAN PING | 05:40 | WARNING |
| host1 | WAN PING | 05:58 | CRITICAL |
| host1 | WAN PING | 06:30 | OK |
| host1 | WAN PING | 06:40 | WARNING |
| host1 | WAN PING | 07:30 | OK |
| host2 | WAN PING | 05:42 | WARNING |
| host2 | WAN PING | 05:46 | OK |
| host2 | WAN PING | 06:40 | WARNING |
| host2 | WAN PING | 06:58 | CRITICAL |
| host2 | WAN PING | 07:30 | OK |
| host3 | WAN PING | 06:30 | WARNING |
| host3 | WAN PING | 07:30 | OK |

I need to return the duration of each alert event.

| host | eventStart | eventEnd | eventDuration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| host1 | 05:40 | 06:30 | 00:50 |
| host1 | 06:40 | 07:30 | 00:50 |
| host2 | 05:42 | 05:46 | 00:04 |
| host2 | 06:40 | 07:30 | 00:50 |
| host3 | 06:30 | 07:30 | 01:00 |

I'm afraid there isn't a unique eventID to group the data and run a `join`

My attempts work for hosts with only one 'event'

```
T
| where Host == 'host3'
| summarize min(eventTime), max(eventTime) by Host
```

Which does return the desired output, but if I run this against `host1` `min=05:40 max=07:30`

Is there a way to group these events by EventStatus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use `row_window_session()`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/row-window-session-function

```
datatable(Host:string, Alert:string, EventTime:datetime, EventStatus:string)
[
    'host1', 'WAN PING', datetime(2020-12-16 05:40), 'WARNING',
    'host1', 'WAN PING', datetime(2020-12-16 05:58), 'CRITICAL',
    'host1', 'WAN PING', datetime(2020-12-16 06:30), 'OK',
    'host1', 'WAN PING', datetime(2020-12-16 06:40), 'WARNING',
    'host1', 'WAN PING', datetime(2020-12-16 07:30), 'OK',
    'host2', 'WAN PING', datetime(2020-12-16 05:42), 'WARNING',
    'host2', 'WAN PING', datetime(2020-12-16 05:46), 'OK',
    'host2', 'WAN PING', datetime(2020-12-16 06:40), 'WARNING',
    'host2', 'WAN PING', datetime(2020-12-16 06:58), 'CRITICAL',
    'host2', 'WAN PING', datetime(2020-12-16 07:30), 'OK',
    'host3', 'WAN PING', datetime(2020-12-16 06:30), 'WARNING',
    'host3', 'WAN PING', datetime(2020-12-16 07:30), 'OK',
]
| order by Host asc, EventTime asc 
| extend session_start = row_window_session(EventTime, 1d, 1d, Host != prev(Host) or prev(EventStatus) == "OK")
| summarize eventStart = min(EventTime), eventEnd = max(EventTime) by session_start, Host
| project Host, eventStart, eventEnd, duration = eventEnd - eventStart
| order by Host asc, eventStart asc
```

Comment: Amazing - exactly what I needed, thank you